# Flexbox child ignores parent's padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox, padding

My `#main` element ignores it's wrapper padding. I set `position:absolute` on children, but when I try to change it from `position:static`,to `position:relative` it just ignores parent's `height`. Any workarounds?

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper-body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#wrapper-header {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 50px;
    background: url("header.png");
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 5;
}
#wrapper-main {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding: 25px;
}
#wrapper-footer {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    background-color: #212121;
}
#menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.menu-button {
    background-color: #3B3B3B;
    width: 100px;
    height: 22px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #F7F7F7;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: "codropsicons", verdana;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.active-button, .menu-button:hover {
    background-color: #E0962D;
}
#main {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#copyright {
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "codropsicons", verdana;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #F7F7F7;
    margin-left: 15px;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-body">
    <div id="wrapper-header">
        <nav id="menu">
            <a class="menu-button active-button">O nas</a>
            <a class="menu-button">Oferta</a>
            <a class="menu-button">Galeria</a>
            <a class="menu-button">Kontakt</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper-main">
        <main id="main">
            Test
            <br> Test
            <br>
        </main>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper-footer">
        <div id="copyright">Koyot © 2017 All rights reserved</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldmmxw9m/3/

Comment: Your `#main` element has `position: absolute;` on it, which will always ignore padding. Remove this property and it should work.

Comment: As i wrote in the question, if i set it to position:relative, it just ignores parent's height and sets its height on 100% of document's height.

Comment: You can't use percentage-based heights on elements whose parent's don't have a set height. Putting a `height` attribute on `wrapper-main` should resolve that issue. Because you're using `flex`, literally putting *any* height (`height: 1px`, `height: 5000px`, etc) on your element should work - flexbox will fix it for you.

Comment: Wont my flexbox breakdown when i set height to 100% when flex is set to auto?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't ignore the parents height when using `position: relative`, it simply keeps the padding of the parent, but apart from that it fills the parent - see my snippet. Of course the parent's height has to be set when you use a percentage value for the child's height...

```css
#wrapper-main{
  flex:1 1 auto;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding:25px;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 200px;
}

#main{
    background-color:green;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-main">
 <main id="main">
some content
 </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Santi said, you can remove `position: absolute` on `#main`, since that will place the element relative to it's nearest positioned ancestor, ignoring the ancestor's padding.

Or if that's not an option, you could use `top/left/right/bottom` values that match the padding amount, and remove the padding on the parent if that's no longer needed.

```css
/* TAGS */

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* END OF TAGS */


/* WRAPPERS */

#wrapper-body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper-header {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  background: url("header.png");
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 5;
}

#wrapper-main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#wrapper-footer {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: #212121;
}


/* END OF WRAPPERS */


/* CONTENT */

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu-button {
  background-color: #3B3B3B;
  width: 100px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #F7F7F7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "codropsicons", verdana;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.active-button,
.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #E0962D;
}

#main {
  background-color: green;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}

#copyright {
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "codropsicons", verdana;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #F7F7F7;
  margin-left: 15px;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper-body">

    <div id="wrapper-header">
      <nav id="menu">
        <a class="menu-button active-button">O nas</a>
        <a class="menu-button">Oferta</a>
        <a class="menu-button">Galeria</a>
        <a class="menu-button">Kontakt</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper-main">
      <main id="main">
        Test
        <br> Test
        <br>
      </main>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper-footer">
      <div id="copyright">Koyot © 2017 All rights reserved</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Remove `position: absolute;` from `#main`.

Absolutely positioned items are "out of the flow". Setting the parent to `relative` will modify the absolute child element's bounding box to it's own height and width, but padding is not taken into account.

**2.** Change the wrapper's `align-items: center;` to `align-items: stretch;`

It seems to me that you don't want the child to be vertically-aligned in the middle, but rather to take up the entire height of the wrapper.  `align-items: stretch` will apply this behavior.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldmmxw9m/5)

```css
/* TAGS */

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* END OF TAGS */


/* WRAPPERS */

#wrapper-body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper-header {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  background: url("header.png");
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 5;
}

#wrapper-main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 25px;
}

#wrapper-footer {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: #212121;
}


/* END OF WRAPPERS */


/* CONTENT */

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu-button {
  background-color: #3B3B3B;
  width: 100px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #F7F7F7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: "codropsicons", verdana;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.active-button,
.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #E0962D;
}

#main {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}

#copyright {
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "codropsicons", verdana;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #F7F7F7;
  margin-left: 15px;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="wrapper-body">

    <div id="wrapper-header">
      <nav id="menu">
        <a class="menu-button active-button">O nas</a>
        <a class="menu-button">Oferta</a>
        <a class="menu-button">Galeria</a>
        <a class="menu-button">Kontakt</a>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper-main">
      <main id="main">
        Test<br> Test
        <br>
      </main>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper-footer">
      <div id="copyright">Koyot © 2017 All rights reserved</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Without a comment, I can only assume the downvote I received was due to bitterness. If someone has an issue with my answer or a reason why it is not correct, please let me know - constructive criticism is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to the parent element:
box-sizing:border-box;

This changes how the width and height is calculated by the browser so it includes padding and borders.  With flex, using border-box on the parent has corrected spacing issues.